# UIStoryboardSegue in MVC-model

Tags: ios, xcode, directory-structure

I am currently making up a directory structure, which is supposed to enable me to work clearer with the MVC model in my iOS-projects. I therefore created a folder for my `Models`, `Views`, `Controllers` and integrated `APIs`, but wonder where to put custom segues. I know that they do not belong to the API directory or to the model, but I would neither add them to the Controllers as segues do not coordinate the workflow and not to the Views as they are not visible or contained in a UIViewController. Are there any suggestions where to put the `UIStoryboardSegue` files? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Segues are meant to perform transition between controller I would put it with the Controllers.

But note that `iOS` framework combines view and controller. This approach is called MVVM, hence the name ViewController. This means it will be tricky  to treat it as pure MVC.

For instance what would be in the view?
Should it be storyboards, or custom view classes?

Comment: I have all the UIView subclasses in the Views directory and my storyboard in the main bundle; I only have one storyboard and consider it to have a special role in my app Design. Additionally as you can configure the ViewControllers in the storyboard but also the Views via IBDesignable I would neither add the storyboard to the Views nor my Controllers. My project is not that huge at the moment, but – excluded the segues – the order makes a lot of sense to me and works (at least so far).